# can't update firebase functions using cli because Default service account doesn't exist

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I realized that my service account credentials were posted to github so I decommissioned them and now I am no longer able to update my firebase functions.

This is the error I get:

```
functions: failed to create function functionName
HTTP Error: 400, Default service account '<APP_ID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist. Please recreate this account (for example by disabling and enabling the Cloud Functions API), or specify a different account.
```

I've tried numerous solutions to no avail.

- disabling and enabling the Cloud Functions API
- [re initializing the sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) - using a newly generated service account. The firebase cli seems to still be using the old account which no longer exists.
- I've contacted firebase support who suggested the second solution above and have been entirely unresponsive for days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar issue I figured out how to fix it:

The key that was leaked was created here:
[image]

I assumed that I had to delete the entire account once that key was leaked, and didn't realize I could just delete that key from the same page:

[image]

Because I deleted the service account less than 30 days ago I was able to [Restore the default service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/default-service-account#restoring_a_deleted_default_service_account_)

If you are outside of the 30-day window I don't think anyone can help you.